# Expected Value Biased Coin

Tags: probability

Suppose that there is a biased coin and we flip the coin until 2 of the most recent 3 flips are heads. Let $p$ be the probability that it is heads. Also, let $X$ be the random variable which represents the total flips. If the first 2 flips are heads, then $X=2$. How can we find the expected value of $X$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer is for $p=\frac12$; you can work it out for general $p$ accordingly.

---

A non-terminal state is characterized by one of three combinations of the last two flips: `TH`, `HT`, `TT`, and the process effectively starts off in state `TT`. The expected numbers of total flips satisfy

\begin{align}
\def\n#1{n_{\textsf{#1}}}
\n{HT}&=1+\frac12\n{TT}\;,\\
\n{TH}&=1+\frac12\n{HT}\;,\\
\n{TT}&=1+\frac12\left(\n{TH}+\n{TT}\right)\;.
\end{align}

Substituting the first equation into the second and then the second into the third yields

$$
\n{TT}=1+\frac12\left(1+\frac12\left(1+\frac12\n{TT}\right)+\n{TT}\right)\;,
$$

with solution $\n{TT}=\frac{14}3$.

Comment: Why are we solving for $n_{TT}$ exactly? I don't understand that step.

Comment: @user329579: Because the way it's set up, you effectively start off as if you'd just got `TT`: If you get `H` on the first flip, you don't stop.

Answer (score 0):

$X$ is also the number of expected more flips if you have just flipped tails-tails.  Let $Y$ be the number of expected more flips if you have just flipped tails-heads and $Z$ the number of expected more flips if you have just flipped heads-tails.  Now write three coupled equations for $X, Y$ and $Z$.

Answer (score 0):

It is reasonably clear that the expectation exists. Let $w$ be the required expectation.  We condition on the results of the first few tosses.

The winning strings are HH, HTH, HTT followed by a winning string, and T followed by a winning string. In the cases HTT followed by a winning string, and T followed by a winning string, the expected number of **additional** tosses required is $w$. Thus
$$w=2p^2+3p^2(1-p)+(3+w)p(1-p)^2+(1+w)(1-p).$$
Solve for $w$.